# What is the MAP keyword in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, emacs

I have been trying to improve my SQL chops a little bit by working through [SQL Koans](http://sqlkoans.com/), since I enjoy the learn-by-doing-and-meditating approach, and my SQL knowledge is lacking. In one set of koans is the following:

```
-- Meditate on MANY-TO-MANY relationships
select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.title
from book b
    join book_to_author_map map on _____.id = _____.book_id
    join author a on _____.author_id = _____.id
where author_id in (1, 5, 6)
```

Having no previous experience with aliasing, and little experience with joins, I was stuck on this problem for a little while. I was stuck longer than necessary though, because in Emacs `sql-mode` the word **`map`** (which I understand now to be an alias for the table `book_to_author_map`) **is highlighted as an SQL keyword**. I spent a lot of time looking for documentation on this keyword, and found nothing (aside from lots of information on [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/)...).

Peeking at the source code for the Emacs `sql-mode` I found that `map` is designated as a keyword as part of `sql-mode-postgres-font-lock-keywords`, so I started to search for `map` in relation to PostgreSQL, and found it in [a list of SQL keywords in the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). The keyword `MAP` is designated as a "non-reserved" keyword for SQL:2003 and a "reserved" keyword for SQL:1999. However, I have been unable so far to find any documentation for this keyword in association with SQL.

My question, more out of curiosity than anything else, is as in the title: **what is the `MAP` keyword in SQL?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a copy of the standard, but judging by the [grammar](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html#map%20category), `MAP WITH <function>` is a clause for the `CREATE ORDERING` statement.

[`CREATE ORDERING`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/create-ordering-statement/) is used to specify a sort order for a user-defined type, though as far as I can tell, the only vendor to have implemented the `MAP WITH` clause is [Teradata](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1144_151K/CREATE_REPLACE_ORDERING.html). It looks like this clause lets you define a sort order for a custom type by providing a function which maps it to an existing type with a known ordering.

There is no such statement in Postgres, which defines sort ordering via [operator classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopclass.html) and [collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcollation.html).